# Irreducibility of $f(x)=x^{q+1}+x+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I want to show that $\mathbb{F}_{q^3} = \mathbb{F}(\gamma)$ when $\gamma ^{q+1}+\gamma +1 = 0$.
I showed that if $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ then $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{q^3}$, one thing in my mind is to show that $\alpha$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'if $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ then $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$'? That doesn't make sense as stated. (More specifically, how do you define an element of $\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$ for that statement?)

Comment: How is the question in the body related to your title?? If $\alpha$ is to generate a cubic extension, then its minimal polynomial should be cubic.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is primitive, element then then $ord(\alpha)=q^3-1$ and so $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and so it is irreducible. Then we have the equality of the fields.

Comment: Why should that be the case? If the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $n$, then $\alpha$ generates the field $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$.

Comment: BTW, good job getting that those solutions belong to the field $\Bbb{F}_{q^3}$!! Not everybody would get that far! (+1). But, once more, this implies that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is cubic (or even linear).

Answer (score 3):

I guess that the question is about the relation between the polynomial $f(x)$ and the minimal polynomials of its roots. You see, there is no reason for $f(x)$ to be irreducible. In fact, when $q>2$ the calculations show that it cannot be!!

---

As a simple example consider the case $q=3$. We are in characteristic three so $f(1)=1+1+1=0$, and therefore $f(x)$ factors as
$$
f(x)=x^4+x+1=(x-1)(x^3+x^2+x-1).
$$
Here the cubic factor is irreducible, because otherwise it would have a linear factor and hence also a zero in $\Bbb{F}_3$.

---

As a way of confirming the OP's findings let me include the following calculation. If $f(\alpha)=0$, then
$$
\alpha^q=\frac{f(\alpha)-\alpha-1}\alpha=-\frac{\alpha+1}\alpha=-1-\frac1\alpha.
$$
Consequently $1/\alpha^q=-\alpha/(\alpha+1)$ and
$$
\alpha^{q^2}=-\frac{\alpha^q+1}{\alpha^q}=-1-\frac1{\alpha^q}=-\frac1{\alpha+1}.
$$
Repeating the dose we then get
$$
\alpha^{q^3}=-1-\frac1{\alpha^{q^2}}=-1+(\alpha+1)=\alpha.
$$
The conclusion is that $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_{q^3}$. This means that the minimal
polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb{F}_q$ is either cubic or linear.

> The polynomial $f(x)$ is a product of linear and cubic factors from $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$. In particular it is reducible whenever $q>2$.

In other words, we are working with the familiar cyclic group of three fractional linear transformations.

---

The other question seems to be whether the zeros of $f(x)$ are primitive elements of the cubic extension. It may happen that no zero of $f(x)$ would be a primitive element of $\Bbb{F}_{q^3}$. As an example let me proffer the case of $q=4$. In this case we have the factorization
$$
f(x)=x^5+x+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)
$$
over $\Bbb{F}_2$. The quadratic factor $x^2+x+1$ splits into a product of irreducibles over $\Bbb{F}_4$, but zeros of the cubic factor $x^3+x+1$ are elements of $\Bbb{F}_8$, thus all of multiplicative order seven. Adjoining a seventh root of unity to $\Bbb{F}_4$ gives $\Bbb{F}_{4^3}$ as promised, but none of the roots of $f(x)$ have order $63$.

In general we can do the following. If $\alpha$ is a zero of $f(x)$ then
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\alpha^{q+1}=-1-\alpha\\
\implies &\alpha^{q(q+1)}=-1-\alpha^q\\
\implies &\alpha^{q^2+q+1}=-\alpha-\alpha^{q+1}\\
\implies &\alpha^{q^2+q+1}=1.
\end{aligned}
$$
So we can conclude that the order of $\alpha$ is a factor of $q^2+q+1$. This is a proper factor of $q^3-1=(q-1)(q^2+q+1)$ unless $q=2$.

> If $q>2$ then none of the zeros of $f(x)$ are primitive elements of $\Bbb{F}_{q^3}$.